# Given filesystem pathname, how to retrieve corresponding ABSOLUTE ITEMIDLIST?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, shell, language-agnostic

Looks like it can be done in one call or two, but which functions i have/must/should to use for that?

I'm looking for best-practice approach, eg: API specially designed for path -> idl translation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's really a file-system path, call [`ILCreateFromPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378420.aspx). If you need to handle non-file-system objects as well (like My Computer, or Network Neighborhood), then use [`SHParseDisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762236.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I was aware of SHParseDisplayName, but behaves too "loose" (in addition to shell namespace extensions, it accepts localized folders, etc)

Comment: Please check out [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227806/on-ilcreatefrompath-and-error-checking) too, thanks!

Comment: `SHParseDisplayName()` is preferred over `ILCreateFromPath()` (Mirosoft says as much).

Comment: And the reason for that, @Remy, is that SHParseDisplayName handles non-file-system items, which I mentioned. If you don't need that, the ILCreateFromPath is fine.

Comment: Except that it offers no error info if it fails, whereas `SHParseDisplayName()` does.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - TeamB, yes, exactly as Rob Kennedy said - i prefer to fail early if input does not map to file system object. Unfortunately, this sacrifices *documented* error information.

Comment: For both constraining to the file system and returning an error, there's `SHILCreateFromPath`. MSDN says it might not work with possible future OSes, works on 2K through 7 now though.