# How will ILCreateFromPath behave when error checking fails?

Tags: windows, shell, delphi, platform-sdk

In the [PSDK reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378420%28VS.85%29.aspx) for `ILCreateFromPath` there is no information how the function behaves when it fails (and, more importantly, how to get extended error information).

What behavior should I expect, and how can I get that error information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not documented anywhere else.  If it fails, it returns a NULL pointer, and there is no extended error info available what that happens.

Use [`SHParseDisplayName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762236.aspx) instead (even Microsoft says it is preferred over `ILCreateFromPath()`).  It returns an `HRESULT`, which contains an error code on failure.